# React, change const to component with props

Tags: reactjs, components, constants

React,

Hello i need change const for component with props.

How can i do it?

```
const renderFieldOne = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (
  <div>
    <div className ="group">
      <input className="text"
      {...input}
      type={type}/>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <span className="highlight"></span>
      <span className="bar"></span>
      {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Do you want to pass props in functional component

Comment: Yes i have component <Multistep/>

And inside it i need consts:

renderFieldOne
renderFieldTwo
renderFieldThree
renderFieldFour

in cases, with props(({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to pass down each prop individually for each function that you needed to call

```
<renderFieldOne
  input={renderFieldOneInputValue} 
  label={renderFieldOneLabelValue}
  type={renderFieldOneTypeValue}
  meta={touched}
/>
```

and then in the renderFieldOne component you can either do

```
const renderFieldOne = ({input, label, type }) => {...}
```

with destructuring it will assign the matching property names/values to the passed in variables, use this as reference https://amido.com/blog/using-es6-destructuring-in-your-react-components/. The names just have to match with the properties

or just do

```
const renderFieldOne = (props) => {...}
and in each place call props.input or whatever prop you are trying to access.
```

Comment: Yes i did it here:

const StepOneFormValidation = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

      <Field name="name"
        type="text"
        component={renderFieldOne}
        label="Username"
        autoFocus
        require/>
      </div>


    </form>
  )
}

Comment: But now i need to pass this const inside other component

Comment: How can i forward props into component like this?

  export class MultiStep extends React.Component {

Comment: let say you have MultiStep component, in which you need to pass renderFieldOne or renderFieldTwo etc, as a component prop in Field component. Am i getting it right

Comment: Maybe i translate too complicated.

I got component:

Multistep <= This have a lot of logic, and i need use case to render suitable consts.

renderFieldOne <= this is pure component above, which create a style & validation of form

StepOneFormValidation <= It's render individual inputs, and later save it to store.

I need in Multistep render Steps[i]FormValidation

Comment: You can call your functional component as <Field name="name" type="text" component={<renderFieldOne label={labelValue}  />} label="Username" autoFocus require/>